# How to convert pdf back to vsd ( pdf was created by visio)

Tags: pdf, conversion, microsoft-visio, svg

I have examined the asked questions  about this topic already, and tried to use inkspace program to convert pdf to svg. After that I ımported svg to visio but it did not work well because it imported just as a image file not as I expected the layers and text as original file.

I know the pdf has been exported by visio .

Is it really  possible to convert back to vsd ( visio file) ? ( as it is known that pdf was for sure created by visio )

Answer (score 1):

In general, no it is not possible to re-create the original file from a PDF.

Information about the original objects is discarded from the print-ready form

Answer (score -2):

I used inspace to make an experiment.

Experiment Steps:

```
1- I created a visio file with shapes inside it. Visio 2013 version.
2- Exported file as a  pdf.
3- Used inkspace ™ to import and convert it to svg.
4- I imported that svg file to visio
5- Success.
```

So some pdf files are reversible.  So have your chance and give a try.

Comment: That is sort of like trying to photocopy a banknote (besides the fact that you can't), it will still look like a banknote and you may find one person to fool but it will not work properly as a banknote.

Comment: @paulHerber could not get the point.

Comment: I got the point 100%. Your step 5 - success. My response, it may look like success but you have not recreated the Visio file, the shapes are not Visio shapes.

Comment: @PaulHerber define visio shapes please